# What happens to Cloud SQL if you reach max queries with pay per use?

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, autoscaling

I'm currently looking into using Google App Engine for a project.

I understand that the main instance will scale by creating a clone of itself.
I understand that Cloud Storage is basically a big bucket for holding static files.
I understand that Cloud SQL is where the data goes.

Now, lets say I use the smallest SQL instance which allows for 25 concurrent connections, with a pay per use plan. If I exceed 25 connections will Google App Engine create an additional database and split requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) and [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloudsql) are totally separate things. One's an application server and the others a relational database. App Engine will never create additional databases (presumably you mean servers?). If you hit the quotas you will get an exception relating to that quota.

On the other hand, Cloud SQL doesn't have to be 'where the data goes'. There is also [Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) - with an API set much more integrated with App Engine. It also scales without you having to worry about things like concurrent connections. If you are starting a new project from scratch, I'd highly recommend checking out the datastore.

Comment: Unfortunately the website in question is a Wordpress site. :( So regarding Cloud SQL, would I just setup a DB powerful enough to handle lots of connections, should the app engine scale?

Comment: Okay, CloudSQL it is then. You can start off with a small instance and increase it if you need to. This is manual, but you should get an idea for which instance you need based on traffic etc

Comment: OK cheers. They're worried that someone big might tweet them and then they get loads of traffic. Which you can't really plan for unless the 'big person' let's you know in advance.